# App stops working when using Line Segment Detector

Tags: android, opencv, crash

I am trying to use Line segment detector to find and create rectangles in Android (as an experiment)
Since I am just starting this is what I have done so far:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
{ 
    gray=inputFrame.gray(); 
    lines=new Mat();
    canvas=new Mat(480,640, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    LineSegmentDetector det=Imgproc.createLineSegmentDetector();
    det.detect(gray,lines);
    det.drawSegments(gray,lines);
    return gray;
}
```

LogCat:

```
03-05 16:21:48.469 17450-17450/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/JavaCameraView: 
Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080
03-05 16:21:48.500 17450-17450/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/JavaCameraView: 
Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080
03-05 16:21:48.535 17450-17450/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/JavaCameraView: 
Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080
03-05 16:21:48.550 17450-17555/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/CameraBridge: 
mStretch value: 1.4
03-05 16:21:48.567 17450-17450/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/JavaCameraView: 
Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080
03-05 16:21:48.601 17450-17450/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/JavaCameraView: 
Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080
03-05 16:21:48.628 17450-17555/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/CameraBridge: 
mStretch value: 1.4
03-05 16:21:48.636 17450-17450/com.kibo.ninad.cropping D/JavaCameraView: 
Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080
```

That is all I get..no error logs

This works fine for a while but then the app crashes without any intimation whatsoever

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

Thanks again!!

[EDIT]

This is what happens when I use `runOnUiThread`

Code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
{
    mRgb=inputFrame.rgba();
    gray=inputFrame.gray();
    lines=new Mat();
    canvas=new Mat(gray.rows(),gray.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    LineSegmentDetector det=Imgproc.createLineSegmentDetector();
    det.detect(gray,lines);
    det.drawSegments(canvas,lines);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lines=new Mat();
            canvas=new Mat(gray.rows(),gray.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            LineSegmentDetector det=Imgproc.createLineSegmentDetector();
            det.detect(gray,lines);
            det.drawSegments(canvas,lines);
        }
    });
    return canvas;
}
```

LogCat:

```
03-05 19:14:10.893 12415-12528/com.kibo.ninad.cropping A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x65400 in tid 12528 (Thread-4)
03-05 19:14:10.893 12415-12532/com.kibo.ninad.cropping A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfd200 in tid 12532 (Thread-4)
03-05 19:14:10.893 12415-12532/com.kibo.ninad.cropping I/libc: Another thread contacted debuggerd first; not contacting debuggerd.
03-05 19:14:10.893 12415-12415/com.kibo.ninad.cropping A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 12415 (.ninad.cropping)
03-05 19:14:10.893 12415-12415/com.kibo.ninad.cropping I/libc: Another thread contacted debuggerd first; not contacting debuggerd.
03-05 19:14:10.894 12415-12531/com.kibo.ninad.cropping A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x32a00 in tid 12531 (Thread-4)
03-05 19:14:10.894 12415-12531/com.kibo.ninad.cropping I/libc: Another thread contacted debuggerd first; not contacting debuggerd.
03-05 19:14:10.894 12415-12529/com.kibo.ninad.cropping A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x97e00 in tid 12529 (Thread-4)
```

It gives out an error like this now called Fatal Signal error

Comment: May be you can pull a logcat?

Comment: There really is no error in the Logcat

Comment: Can you run your this code in `runOnUiThread() ` and then try again? May be running on separate thread might be helpful.

Comment: @Java_User the `onCameraFrame()` function needs to return the Mat object for display on screen. For that the code for the Line Segment detection needs to be synchronous with it. I quite frankly haven't worked that much with threads. If you know of a way that would make a thread return a Mat object to the function mentioned above then maybe it would work

Comment: Check if this helps .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828704/android-opencv-app-crashes-on-ui-change

Comment: Hey so now I get an error log please check

Comment: `lines=new Mat();
    canvas=new Mat(gray.rows(),gray.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    LineSegmentDetector det=Imgproc.createLineSegmentDetector();
    det.detect(gray,lines);
    det.drawSegments(canvas,lines);`
These lines of code is repeating. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes! this helps me get the lines in real time