# opencv onCameraFrame attempt to invoke TextView.setText()

Tags: multithreading, textview, android, android-runonuithread, opencv

When I try to use setText() inside the onCameraFrame, I experience this crash:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Basically I have the same problem described here:
[Android & OpenCV - App crashes on UI change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828704/android-opencv-app-crashes-on-ui-change)

but the proposed solution appears not to work.

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    frame=inputFrame.rgba();
    int match_method = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF;

    // / result matrix
    int result_cols = frame.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = frame.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    // / Matching
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(frame, frame, result, match_method);

    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTextElement.setText("aa");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved including in the run() the findViewByID, that otherwise returns null. and setText() raises an exception.